python import a dict from another file , but it seems like create a new dict
Question is when I import a dict , I think it is a global var, but python seems create a new dict，they have different id. I cannot understand
There are two files named main.py and add_cache.py
# main.py
d = {}
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from add_cache import AddDictTest
    AddDictTest.add_to_dict("a")
    AddDictTest.add_to_dict("b")
    print("d id is ", id(d))
    print(d)

#add_cache.py
class AddDictTest(object):
    @classmethod
    def add_to_dict(cls, key):
        from main import d
        tt = d.setdefault(key, {})
        tt["b"] = "b"
        print("d id is ", id(d))

when I run main.py
#output is 
d id is  2175240751296
d id is  2175240751296
d id is  2175238904384
{}

In my understand, d is not be empty, and there id should same.
I want to know why create a new empty dict when import , I have ask gpt, it give a answer about cycle import. But I still can not understand deep reason.

This is because the main program is imported and cached as a module under the name __main__ when the Python interpreter starts, creating a dict instance of d in the namespace of the __main__ module.
So when you import the main program with the name main instead:
from main import d

the import system can't find the name main in the module cache, and thereby executes the code of the main program again, creating a new dict instance of d in the namespace of the main module.
This behavior can be verified by simply adding an output of __name__ in your main program:
# main.py
print('creating d in', __name__)
d = {}
...

Your program will then output something like:
creating d in __main__
creating d in main
d id is  124515429184320
d id is  124515429184320
d id is  124515428819648
{}

A simple fix is to explicitly import the __main__ module instead, by changing:
from main import d

to:
from __main__ import d

But that will prevent your other modules from becoming an entry point of the program. A better approach would be to create all the global variables in a separate module such as settings.py, so that all the modules including the main module can do instead:
from settings import d

